# django, trying to manipulate queryset and return to template

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to perform an operation on all the elements from a single field of a model, but I'm getting an error:

```
list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Here's my index function in views.py:

```
design_list = Design.objects.values_list().order_by('-date_submitted')[:10]

x=list(design_list)
for i in x:
    b = list(x[i]) # ERROR RELATES TO THIS LINE
    c = b[2]
    b[2] = datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(c) 
    new_list[i] = b

return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'design_list': new_list,    
})
```

I'm sure this is a common problem, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not C - the `for x in y` loop does not loop over indices, but over the items themselves.

`design_list` is a [list of tuples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), so you can treat it as such. Tuples are immutable, therefore you'll need to create a new list. A list comprehension would probably be best.

```
# Create a new list of tuples
new_list = [row[:2] + (datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(row[2]),) + row[3:]
            for row in x]
```

However, it doesn't seem like you really need to use tuples, since you were confused by the error. If this is the case, then don't use `values_list` (which returns tuples), but just use `order_by`, and reference the field directly (I'll assume it's called `date_submitted`).

```
design_list = Design.objects.order_by('-date_submitted')[:10]

x=list(design_list)
for row in x:
    row.date_submitted = datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(row.date_submitted) 

return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'design_list': x,
})
```

Comment: Fantastic. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in x:` iterates over the *values* of `x`, not the indices. Without analyzing the intent behind the code (and the proper use of QuerySets), the line could be changed to:

```
b = list(i)
```

to avoid this particular error.